Versions in the dependency graph in modules and the actual modules in the pack in Ballerina
What are the scenarios can a version of a dependency of module foo (let's say bar)  differs from the version packed in the pack?
Let's take crypto module. It is a dependency of module auth. When we check the 2201.8.6-swan-lake pack, we can see that, in the dependency-graph.json of auth, it says 2.5.0 as the version of the crypto. But, once we search for the crypto module packed with the pack is actually 2.6.2.

Can you be a bit more specific? What do you mean by the pack? Concrete package names will be useful

Updated the question with actual scenario

The answer is simple: we package the latest compatible versions of ballerina/* packages when we release Ballerina platform distribution, such as Swan Lake Update 8.6.
ballerina/auth:2.5.0 - Released 10 months ago
ballerina/crypto:2.6.2 - Released 7 months ago. 

Ballerina Swan Lake Update 8.6 - Released 3 months ago. 

This strategy makes sense because that's exactly how the Ballerina Dependency resolver works. Do you see any issues with this approach?

What happens if someone who is in offline mode now tries to build a package which was previously built with a previous Ballerina pack version?
Here, the Dependency.toml of his package says crypto is 2.5.0. The current pack (2201.8.6) has ballerina/crypto:2.6.2 and the dependency-graphy.json of ballerina/auth also says crypto is 2.5.0. Now when resolving dependencies, they get an error error: failed to load the module 'ballerina/auth:2.10.0' from its BIR due to: cannot resolve module ballerina/crypto:2.5.0 since  ballerina/crypto:2.5.0 is not there to solve.

@DulajDilshan Didi you use the sticky flag(--sticky). Otherwise, Ballerina resolves to the ballerina/crypto:2.6.2 version.
